# 2D map translation computation

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to find an algorithm that given two 2D images where one image is a "shift" of the other, to compute the optimal shift.  A shift is a simple translation with no rotation.

The motivation is I have a series of images that are portions of a big map, and I want to combine them.  Imagine going to Google Maps, take a screenshot, shift the map slightly, then take another, and so on.

Right now I have a simple algorithm.  I take the second image, and try all small shifts say from -9 to +9 in both dimensions.  Then I use some template matching algorithm like OpenCV's matchTemplate(), and pick the best one.  This is inefficient, does not support large translation, and does not support subpixel translation.

I can't find anything in OpenCV to do this - I was hoping at the very least there would be some parallelized version of the above simple algorithm, but I can't find it.  Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the images are not necessarily *exactly* shifted copies of each other -- if they were, you could use a 2D pattern-matching algorithm like the Baker-Bird algorithm to look for exact matches.  Other people may have developed approximate forms of matching based on this algorithm.

Comment: Sounds like Image stitching? http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/introduction.html http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cheap and easy idea:**
A cheaper approach than shifting the entire second image -9 to +9 might be to take a single row in the second image and find the best matching row in the first image. Do the same for a single column. You can compute row/column similarity using something simple like using the absolute difference of the row/column vectors. This might give you an easy translation between the images.

**Some more advanced alternatives:**
You might be able to estimate some type of transformation between the images (e.g., affine transformation) using [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) or [SURF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF) image features. See this: [Estimating an Affine Transform between Two Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758570/estimating-an-affine-transform-between-two-images)

More resources: 
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html

Another idea is to use [optical flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow) to find a pixel-based mapping between the images.

More resources:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html

These two approaches might be overkill since you seem to be dealing with a transformation of a static image. The SIFT/SURF features might make it easy to learn the transformation though.

Comment: Thanks.  The idea seem to be, comparing the whole image is inefficient, so compare small representative portions.  I think some variant of this might work.  I'll try tonight to roll my own feature detection (better than single row/col, but maybe not SIFT/SURF) - should be easy to find small colorful patches.  If that doesn't work I'll try the SURF approach from the link you gave which should work.